# How do I create a view that turns one line into multiple line based on a quantity in another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working with Microsoft SQL

I have a table CR_INVLINES that shows something like below

```
STOCKCODE     QTY   BARCODE  
GUITAR101     3     456812313
DESK          1     568123122
LAMP          2     845646962
```

*What I need my view to return is the lines at the multiples of the qty like below:*

```
STOCKCODE       BARCODE
GUITAR101       456812313
GUITAR101       456812313
GUITAR101       456812313
DESK            568123122
LAMP            845646962
LAMP            845646962
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the result:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM CR_INVLINES
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT stockcode, qty-1, BARCODE
    FROM CTE
    WHERE qty-1 >= 1
)
SELECT STOCKCODE, Barcode
FROM CTE
order by stockcode
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d44f/4)

This gives the result:

```
| STOCKCODE |   BARCODE |
-------------------------
|      DESK | 568123122 |
| GUITAR101 | 456812313 |
| GUITAR101 | 456812313 |
| GUITAR101 | 456812313 |
|      LAMP | 845646962 |
|      LAMP | 845646962 |
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much I have applied this to the DB and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for this, you need a numbers table.  Here is a quick-and-easy solution that works in many cases:

```
with numbers as (
       select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as num
      )
select il.stockcode, barcode
from CR_INVLINES il join
     numbers n
     on il.qty <= n.num
```

A more formal answer goes like this:

```
with digits as (
     select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
     select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
   ),
   numbers as (
    select d1.d*100+d2.d*10+d3.d
    from digits d1 cross join digits d2 cross join digits d3
   )
select il.stockcode, barcode
from CR_INVLINES il join
     numbers n
     on il.qty < n.num
```

(Note the `<=` changed to `<` because the set of numbers now has a 0.)